# Not able to setLayoutManager to RecyclerView. Showing null pointer on the RecyclerView

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-recyclerview

I have the following code in my `onCreate` function of my activity:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    LinearLayoutManager manager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    manager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(manager);
    setContentView(R.layout.my_layout);
    // some more code
```

and `my_layout.xml` looks as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/annonce.main.coordinator"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout...>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        app:behavior_overlapTop="78dp"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/card_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp">

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/listView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
                android:scrollbars="vertical"
                app:behavior_overlapTop="78dp"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
            </ListView>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I am getting the error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method void 
android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.setLayoutManager(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager) on a null object reference` in the line recyclerView.setLayoutManager(manager);
```

I did try going through similar queries in previous sof articles, but none of them seemed to solve my problem much. Can you please tell me where I am going wrong in my code here? Thanks.

Comment: move `setContentView(R.layout.my_layout);` to top after `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);`

Comment: That throws the error `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: RecyclerView has no LayoutManager` which is the very reason I added the `LinearLayoutManager` code before that.

Comment: Sorry I just noticed. Your layout is wrong. RecyclerView can only contain views populated by a **RecylerViewAdapter**. Check this link to learn how to use RecyclerView http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/getting-started-with-recyclerview-and-cardview-on-android--cms-23465

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1)** Like mentioned in "@Much Overflow" answer, change your `onCreate()` method to:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.my_layout); // setting the layout first

    LinearLayoutManager manager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    manager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(manager);
}
```

**2)** Remove extra childs from your `RecyclerView` xml.

Your `my_layout.xml` should looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/annonce.main.coordinator"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout...>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        app:behavior_overlapTop="78dp"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

And if you want to add views in your `RecyclerView`, you should use the `Adapter`.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to find the RecyclerView before setting your layout. Do this

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.my_layout); // setting the layout first

    LinearLayoutManager manager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    manager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(manager);
}
```

Comment: Doing the above throws the error `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: RecyclerView has no LayoutManager` on the line `setContentView(R.layout.my_layout);`

Comment: Sorry I just noticed. Your layout is wrong. RecyclerView can only contain views populated by a **RecylerViewAdapter**. Check this link to learn how to use RecyclerView http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/getting-started-with-recyclerview-and-cardview-on-android--cms-23465

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have a CardView and a listView inside RecyclerView? I have never seen such a layout. There is something wrong with your layout.

Try to remove the children of recyclerView from the layout file.

Comment: So I will need to remove the CardView from there to some other xml file, and then include that new xml file inside that removed part inside the RecyclerView?

Comment: RecyclerView uses an adapter that acts as the bridge between the data and the rows shown in the recyclerview. The adapter is associated with a ViewHolder that encapsulates the view. If you look at a simple sample that demonstrates RecyclerView, it will be clear. [link](http://developer.android.com/samples/RecyclerView/index.html)